# Same NN architecture giving different accuracies in tensor flow and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

A neural network trained on iris dataset using [4, 4] hidden layers and created separately in tensorflow and keras gives different results.

While the tensorflow model gives 96.6 % accuracy on test, keras model gives only around 50%. The various hyper parameters like learning rate, optimiser, mini batch size, etc were the same in both cases.

**Keras model**

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(units = 4, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 4))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(units = 4, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(units = 3, activation = 'softmax'))

adam = Adam(epsilon = 10**(-6), lr = 0.01)
model.compile(optimizer = 'adagrad', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

one_hot_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes = 3)

model.fit(X_train, one_hot_labels, epochs = 50, batch_size = 40)
```

**Tensorflow model**

```
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key = name,
                                                   shape = (1),
                                                   dtype = tf.float32) for name in list(X_train.columns)]

classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units = [4, 4],
                                       feature_columns = feature_columns,
                                       n_classes = 3,
                                       dropout = 0.25,
                                       model_dir = './DNN_model')

train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x = X_train,
                                              y = y_train,
                                              batch_size = 40,
                                              num_epochs = 50,
                                              shuffle = False)

classifier.train(input_fn = train_input_fn, steps = None)
```

For the keras model, I did try changing the learning rate, increasing the number of epochs, using different optimisers, etc. As such, the accuracy remained poor. Clearly, both the models are doing different things, but on the surface, they seem identical to me for all the key aspects.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this also happen when using the model class API?

Answer (score 3):

they have **the same architecture**, and that's all.

The difference in performance is coming from one or more of these factors:

- You have Dropout. Therefore your networks in every start behaving differently (check how the Dropout works);
- Weight initializations, which method you're using in Keras and TensorFlow?
- Check **all** parameters of the optimizer.

Comment: - **Dropout**: I ran both several times. I get similar results for both every time.
- **Weight initialisations**: I haven't changed the defaults. But I think it is fair to assume that it uses xavier initialiser. 
- **Optimizer**: I tried changing the learning rate and the epsilon value for the optimisers. In fact, for the keras model, I tried several optimisers and learning rates. Its performance is still bad.

Comment: are you sure the defaults for keras and TF are the same?